# assertThat() is always successful

Tags: junit, assert, assertj

I have a test that doesn't fail when it should:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@Test
public void testTransactionResponse() {
    String id= "004";
    long amount= 5000001L;
    TransactionResource transactionResource = buildTransactionResource(amount, "EUR");
    System.out.println(transactionController.create(id, transactionResource).getStatusCode()); //the output is 403
    assertThat(transactionController.create(id, transactionResource).getStatusCode().equals(200)); //is true and test doesn't fail
}
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[assertThat](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat-boolean-) returns [BooleanAssert](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/BooleanAssert.html) and doesn't actually assert anything.

AssertJ provides fluent API so you're expected to call assert methods after that:

```
assertThat(
    transactionController.create(id, transactionResource).getStatusCode().equals(200)
).isTrue();
```

But it doesn't seem that you need AssertJ for that. JUnit's own [assertTrue](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)) would suffice:

```
 assertTrue(transactionController.create(id, transactionResource).getStatusCode().equals(200));
```

or even better, [assertEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(long,%20long)):

```
 assertEquals(200, transactionController.create(id, transactionResource).getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
assertThat(operation.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
```

As @default locale stated, it is true that `assertThat(false)` does not check anything, you can detect this bad usage with findbugs as explained here http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core.html#faq-incorrect-api-usage.